# How to use adb to install and debug an app in a work profile?

Tags: android, adb

I developed an android app which works fine. But if I install it into a [Work Profile](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles), it *sometimes* fails. The installation into a Work Profile is currently done by distributing the app via a private Google PlayStore (only company users will be able to download it).

Any way I can use 'adb' to install the apk into Work Profile directly? And I need to debug the app running inside a Work Profile as well.

Answer (score 12):

Here you find the documentation for adb which is used to install and start the app: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

You see there that (unfortunately) it is not possible to install the app for only one user. But it is possible to start and debug it "in the name" of a specific user.

So what you have to do is the following:

1. find out the userId of the desired user
2. set the userId in your Run Configuration

**Step 1**

To find out the userId of the desired user, open your terminal and enter

```
$> adb shell dumpsys user
```

You'll get a list about all the user information of the connected device. Somewhere in this list you should also find your user similar to this: `UserInfo{10:Work profile:30}`

This means that **10** is your userId.

**Step 2**

Now go to AndroidStudio -> Run -> Edit Configurations. Select your current Run Configuration and in the field for Launch Flags enter `--user 10`

If you click the Run or Debug button now, the app will be installed for all user and started with the user with *userId 10*

Comment: unable to install on samsung note work profile using this.

Comment: read carefully. you cannot *install* on one profile. You always must install the app on both profiles. But you can *start* the app directly with your work profile. So the "--user XX" flag must be entered in the Launch Flags. Also make sure to execute Step 1, to find out your device-specific userIds

Comment: Works like charm on the work profile emulated by Test DPC app.

Answer (score 10):

As a complement to @muetzenflo's answer, in case you want to run your application via command-line, all you need to do is:

```
$ adb shell pm list users
```

Output will be similar to this:

```
UserInfo{0:Drew:13} running
UserInfo{10:Work profile:30} running
```

Get the user id of your work profile and call `am start` with `--user` flag:

```
$ adb shell am start --user 10 \
  -n "com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.testactivity" \
  -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

You can read more at Android's official page on [Work profiles](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles).